# Getting table value from nowgoal has got an index error

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am quite new to scraping. I am getting links from [nowgoal](http://www.nowgoal3.com/). Below is how I started navigating to above page. I do not wish to get link for all matches. But I will have an input text file, which is [attached here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZAaBOVFUUn9Mww7i_JRaEwSn5utaLGrF/view?usp=sharing) and use the selected league and date.

The following code will initialize as input:

```
#Intialisation
league_index =[]
final_list = []
j = 0
#config load
config = RawConfigParser()
configFilePath = r'.\config.txt'
config.read(configFilePath)
date = config.get('database_config','date')                     #input file provided by user - provide in YYYY-MM-DD format
leagues = config.get('database_config','leagues')               #input file provided by user - provide in windows format
headless_param =config.get('database_config','headless')        #Headless param - set True if you want to see bowser operating in foreground!
leagues_list = leagues.split(',')
print(leagues_list)
```

After I initialized with the preferred date and league, I will set up for chrome driver as follow:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()         #initialise webdriver options
#options.binary_location = brave_path        #if you are running the script on brave - then enable it
if headless_param == 'True' :
    print('headless')
    options.headless = True                 # if headeless parameter is set to true - the chrome browser will not appear in foreground
options.add_argument('start-maximized')     # Start the chrome maximised 
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')    # Disable infobars
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 2})
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.block_third_party_cookies": True})
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--incognito")         #Incognito mode


#intiate the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(resource_path('./drivers/chromedriver.exe'),options=options) 
#Format the url

url =  'http://www.nowgoal3.com/football/fixture/?f=ft0&date='+date


#get the url
driver.get(url)
#wait for some time
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="li_league"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
#click on the -team ranking
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="TeamOrderCheck"]').click()
```

After this, you will be brought to the following [page](http://www.nowgoal3.com/football/fixture/?type=&f=sc1&date=2021-01-28)

I also add in the snap shot below [image: here]

I try to get the data from the table by looping: the code is as follow:

```
> #Get the leagues name from page htmlSource = driver.page_source
> #Pass the htmlsource into soup soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmlSource,'html.parser')
> #Table table = soup.select('table[id="table_live"]')
> #Rows of table all_rows = table[0].select('tr')
> #loop through each row 
for i , row in enumerate(all_rows[2:]) :
>     try:
>         key_word = row['class'][0]
>         print(key_word)
>         if 'Leaguestitle' in key_word:#if leagues got changed
>             league = row.a.text
>             print(row.a.text)
>             if row.a.text in leagues_list:
>                 j =1
>             else:
>                 j =0                
>         elif j== 1:
>             home_team = row.findAll('a')[0].text                                                #home team
>             print(home_team)
>             away_team = row.findAll('a')[1].text                                                #away team
>             match_number = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit,row.findAll('a')[2]['href'].strip()))    
> #match_number
>             link  = 'http://data.nowgoal.group/3in1odds/'+match_number+'.html'            
> #link for 3 in 1 odds from the match code
>             home_ranking = row.findAll('span')[0].text.strip('[]')                              #home team ranking
>             away_ranking = row.findAll('span')[1].text.strip('[]')                              #Away team ranking
>             final_list.append([home_team,home_ranking,away_team,away_ranking,league,match_number,link])
>     except KeyError:
>         try:
>             if row['style']=='display:none':
>                 continue
>             elif j== 1:
>                 home_team = row.findAll('a')[0].text                                            #home team
>                 away_team = row.findAll('a')[1].text                                            #away team
>                 home_ranking = row.findAll('span')[0].text.strip('[]')                          #home team ranking
>                 away_ranking = row.findAll('span')[1].text.strip('[]')                          #Away team ranking
>                 match_number = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit,row.findAll('a')[2]['href'].strip()))
> #match_code associated with each match
>                 link  = 'http://data.nowgoal.group/3in1odds/'+match_number+'.html'            
> #link for 3 in 1 odds from the match code
>                 final_list.append([home_team,home_ranking,away_team,away_ranking,league,match_number,link])
>         except KeyError :
>             print('KeyError')
>             
> 
>     except IndexError:
>         if j== 1:
>             home_team = row.findAll('a')[0].text                                            #home team
>             away_team = row.findAll('a')[1].text                                            #away team
>             home_ranking = row.findAll('span')[0].text.strip('[]')                          #home team ranking
>             away_ranking = row.findAll('span')[1].text.strip('[]')                          #Away team ranking
>             match_number = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit,row.findAll('a')[2]['href'].strip()))
> #match_code associated with each match
>             link  = 'http://data.nowgoal.group/3in1odds/'+match_number+'.html'            
> #link for 3 in 1 odds from the match code
>             final_list.append([home_team,home_ranking,away_team,away_ranking,league,match_number,link])
>             print('IndexError-captured')        
> 
> print(final_list)#show the final result driver.quit()#close the
> browser
```

Then I print out the hometeam and the following results

> Chelsea adtext-bg QC: MAY88.COM - NHÀ CÁI HỢP PHÁP NA UY - THƯỞNG NẠP
> 100% - HOÀN TRẢ 100TR - HỖ TRỢ 24/7

Then it threw me an index error as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Football matters/Sttratagem data access/Games By Numbers/Nowgoal scraping project/codes/NOWGOAL-20200721T024808Z-001/NOWGOAL/PYFILES/Link_extractor_v1.3.py", line 124, in <module>
    away_team = row.findAll('a')[1].text                                                #away team
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Football matters/Sttratagem data access/Games By Numbers/Nowgoal scraping project/codes/NOWGOAL-20200721T024808Z-001/NOWGOAL/PYFILES/Link_extractor_v1.3.py", line 149, in <module>
    away_team = row.findAll('a')[1].text                                            #away team
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Print out row and check if the a tags are in there.

Comment: Dear Chohan, I can see the following under hometeam print out ; Chelsea adtext-bg QC: MAY88.COM - NHÀ CÁI HỢP PHÁP NA UY - THƯỞNG NẠP 100% - HOÀN TRẢ 100TR - HỖ TRỢ 24/7
After that it stopped.

Comment: So basically, I want to get the hometeam, home team ranking, away team, awayteam ranks from the table, and links for each match that can give me odds.

Comment: Rank is represented the number within the square bracket. The link for each match can be obtained by clicking the button beside the football field button.

Comment: This should do what you want if you add your checks in.

Answer (score 2):

```
league_list = league_list = ["English Premier League", 'Italian Serie A',
                             'England Championship', 'Spanish La Liga', 'Swedish Allsvenskan', 'USA Major League Soccer','Saudi','Dutch Cup']
#wait for some time



# wait for some time
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "li_league"))).click()
# click on the -team ranking
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//label[@for='TeamOrderCheck']/span"))).click()

for league in league_list:
    try:
        nextRow = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//tr[.//a[contains(text(),"{}")]]'.format(league))))
        id = nextRow.get_attribute("id").split("_")[1]
        try:

            row = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.XPATH, '//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[.//a[contains(text(),"{}")]] and following-sibling::tr[@id="tr_{}"] and not(@style="display:none")]'.format(league, int(id)+1))))
            print("########The result for {} ########".format(league))
            for i in row:
                print(i.get_attribute("textContent"))
            print("###########Completed##############".format(league))
        except:
            row = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.XPATH, '//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[.//a[contains(text(),"{}")]] and not(@style="display:none")]'.format(league))))
            print("########The result for {} ########".format(league))
            for i in row:
                print(i.get_attribute("textContent"))
            print("###########Completed##############".format(league))
            continue
    except:
        continue
```

you can use following and preceeding property , as there is no unique way to identify next following element we have to take id and increment it with 1

Comment: only gets the first row and not all of them.

Comment: let me check , sure

Comment: //tr[preceding-sibling::tr[@class="Leaguestitle fbHead"][.//a[text()= 'Spanish La Liga']] and not(@style="display:none") and not(@class="adtext-bg") and following-sibling::tr[@class="Leaguestitle fbHead"][.//a[text() = 'German Bundesliga']]]

Comment: yes that works only if we know the next title , the given solution is to find element between any tag

Comment: Here i find elements between  elements having id tr_n and tr_n+1

Comment: For last element there is no tr_n+1 so we check only preceeding element not the following

Comment: Hi  @PDHide, thanks for the advice, based in PD code, I cannot have the link but I also see the advert line  as follow, QC: MAY88.COM - NHÀ CÁI HỢP PHÁP NA UY - THƯỞNG NẠP 100% - HOÀN TRẢ 100TR - HỖ TRỢ 24/7

Comment: you can modify it as you want just add not(some condition )

Comment: just add  the condition and not(@class="adtext-bg") to not have adtext

Comment: @PDHide removing the adv works fine, Can you advise me on the link of the match. The link will basically get me to another page which contains 3 in 1 odds. after the link is added, I want to save it in the excel file.

Comment: Could you mention whic helement or attribute you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Prints all the information of each row.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.get('http://www.nowgoal3.com/football/fixture/?type=&f=sc1&date=2021-01-29')
league_list=["English Premier League",'Italian Serie A','England Championship','Spanish La Liga', 'Swedish Allsvenskan','USA Major League Soccer','Swiss Challenge League']
#wait for some time
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "li_league"))).click()
#click on the -team ranking
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='TeamOrderCheck']/span"))).click()

for league in league_list:
    try:  
        header = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='Leaguestitle fbHead']/td[2]/span/a[text()='"+league+"']")
        #print(len(header))
        print(header.text)
        nextRow = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//tr[.//a[contains(text(),"{}")]]'.format(league))))
        id = nextRow.get_attribute("id").split("_")[1]
        try:

            rows = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.XPATH, '//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[.//a[contains(text(),"{}")]] and following-sibling::tr[@id="tr_{}"] and not(@style="display:none")]'.format(league, int(id)+1))))
     
        except:
            rows = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.XPATH, '//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[.//a[contains(text(),"{}")]] and not(@style="display:none")]'.format(league))))

            continue
        #print(len(rows))
        for row in rows:
            home = row.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-child(5) > a").text
            homeRank = row.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-child(5)  span.team-hg").text.strip('[]') 
            away = row.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-child(7) > a").text
            awayRank = row.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-child(7)  span.team-hg").text.strip('[]')
            link = row.find_element_by_css_selector("td.toolimg >a:nth-child(3)").get_attribute('href')
            link = ''.join(filter(lambda i: i.isdigit(), link))
            link  = 'http://data.nowgoal.group/3in1odds/'+link+'.html'
            print(home,homeRank,away,awayRank,link)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Hi Chohan,Thanks a lot,
When I used the input league from the txt file that is attached in  the post, it got me the following error. I do not want to get full table yet with the selected league, which is found in txt file. The error is below: Traceback (most recent call last):
 
    homeRank = row.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-child(5)  span.team-hg").text.strip('[]')

Comment: @zephyr added league text to check if you want certain ones.

Comment: Hi Chohan, I appreciate much your help and being patient with me. Below is the list of league for 29-01-2021 [GMT Time]
[ 'German Bundesliga', 'Italian Serie A', 'Spanish La Liga', 'France Ligue 1]. That means I am getting the links for upcoming matches. I will only get 4 matches.  Above code get me all the previous matches and upcoming matches. I am still getting the leagues and still running for 3 mins. I will provide the list of league using a text file for specific day. thanks a lot

Comment: As long as you do if league.text in : then do the rest it should work. Just check if the text is in your config file and it should be good.

Comment: There is a faster way that finds all values inside your list which I'm currently unsure how to do. Which use /a[text()='listvalue'] and find_element while looping through your list which should improve the speed a ton.

Comment: Thanks let me try out later as I am currently outside.

Comment: Seems it's still a little bugged. Trying to get between two tags.

Comment: Could you explain more cleanrly what was the issue @ArundeepChohan

Comment: So the issue was that when it gets the row with the league text Italian Serie A the rows underneath that contain tr_1 in it's id all need to be grabbed. It grabs all the rows instead of the few between the league text names. The rows needs to grab just between <tr>certain text</tr> ------ all same line trs with ids------ <tr>not certain text</tr>.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan added an anaswer