# Unable to Upload PDF from Computer to web using selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I worte this code to upload a PDF from computer to website -

```
uploadPdf = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="lazyAttachCV"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section')))
uploadPdf.click()
```

With the above code line I was able to open up the upload popup
[the poped Computer window - example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7jl5.jpg)

and then I again edited the code to fetch the pdf file from G drive and the code is

```
uploadPdf = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="lazyAttachCV"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section'))).send_keys("G://Python Project/Gabi.pdf")
uploadPdf.click()
```

I tried to use the above code, to choose the pdf from G drive but I ended with an trace back error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python Project\Naukri Autamation\main.py", line 39, in <module>
    uploadResume = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="lazyAttachCV"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section'))).send_keys("G://Python Project/Gabi.pdf")
  File "G:\Python Project\Naukri Autamation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "G:\Python Project\Naukri Autamation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "G:\Python Project\Naukri Autamation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "G:\Python Project\Naukri Autamation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)
```

I dont know how to code to upload the pdf from computer to web, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### you cannot interact with windows pop using selenium Instead find the input tag element and send file path to that

eg

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("input").send_keys("c://a.pdf")
```

Comment: Autoit might be able to do what he wants. Also have you tried getting elements between two tags I'm having an issue with another question.

Comment: you can use any other tool or library to interact with Download prompt but selenium cannot . If the usecase is just to upload file then you cna use send_keys

Comment: @ArundeepChohan could you add the question link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65929976/getting-table-value-from-nowgoal-has-got-an-index-error?answertab=active#tab-top   The issue is getting rows.

Comment: @PDHide I'm sorry can you please let me know what value should be used in("input"), affter the window popsup, please?

Comment: you don't have to click the upload button uploadPdf.click() remove this line , fond input tag and send_keys

Comment: Hi, @PDHide so I understood what you said and with small mod I was able to complete the task thankyou so much `uploadResume.find_element_by_id("attachCV").send_keys("G://Python Project/Gabi - Resume.pdf")` and @Arundeep Chochan thanks to you too.

Comment: @PDHide can you please take a look at this link please [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65987801/closing-popup-windows-in-selenium-using-python]