# Closing Popup windows in Selenium using python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, popupwindow

I am trying to close popup windows, and the handler values are not fixed, they change every time when run again. I thought of pulling the pop title and using for loop to close() the popups but the popup didn't have a title.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://www.naukri.com/')
# driver.maximize_window()

parent = driver.current_window_handle
print(f"This is parent window : {parent}")

uselessWindows = driver.window_handles
print(f"This has the parent window and also the two popup windows : {uselessWindows}")
```

and the output is

```
This is parent window : CDwindow-196D8EFD5DD167AUTHE8935233FE0140 #String Value
This has the parent window and also the two popup window : ['CDwindow-196D8EFD5DD167AUTHE8935233FE0140', 'CDwindow-9E2058C9AADEWDHUIO4758B2F378AF577', 'CDwindow-94B59B8JGUTJ46578DHKDLNM24658C7C'] #List Value
```

Every time the value after "CDwindow -" changes every single time and I am unable to use set difference `-` because the `current_window_handle` is in the string and the `window_handles` is in List. Kindly help me with a solution to close the popups.

Comment: Basically it's a combination of PDHide and Buabans answer of removing the useless windows and switching back to parent.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan thankyou soo much, _/\_

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
parent = driver.current_window_handle
print(f"This is parent window : {parent}")

uselessWindows = driver.window_handles
print(
    f"This has the parent window and also the two popup windows : {uselessWindows}")
driver.switch_to.window(uselessWindows[-1])
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(uselessWindows[0])
```

the pop up window is the last element in the list you can use above code , you have to switch back to parent to continue execution

Comment: Okay thankyou soo much pdhide, I have clarrification may I ask?

Comment: Sure please ask

Comment: thankyou once again pdhide, in this scenario we have fixed number of popups so we used -1, what if there are so many popups(which will be determined only after we run website), so in this case we cant prejudge how many popups so what can be done and we only want to use the first one alone and how to close other popups,

Comment: @Gab0623 you can use buabans answer iterating through the windows handle and at out side of for loop use driver.switch_to.window(parent)

Comment: Thankyou Hide for the explanation

Comment: Is this solution always deterministic?

Answer (score 3):

You have to iterate through the list of window handles, and close the one which is not the parent.

```
driver.get('https://www.naukri.com/')
parent = driver.current_window_handle
uselessWindows = driver.window_handles
for winId in uselessWindows:
    if winId != parent: 
        driver.switch_to.window(winId)
        driver.close()
```

Comment: Hi buaban when the code is excuted I am getting this error when the code is trying to proceed further `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed` after executing above code the code is showing that error.

Comment: this is the cleanest close popup code I found anywhere!